# Difference between Postman and a simple Http Request with superagent

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, http-status-code-301, superagent

I was wondering what's the difference between a simple POST request with superagent and a POST request with Postman.
Because Im trying to scrap a website, so I made a post request with Postman and everythings work fine, I got the result expected. But when I proceed a POST Http request with superagent, I got a 301 redirect.

There's a way to pass this problem in having the same result as Postman ?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Paul, please, add your code to your next question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `redirects`. Simple example:

```
const request = require('superagent');
const url = 'localhost:3000/example';
request
.post(url)
.send({msg: "hello"})
.redirects(1) //Add redirect functionality
.on('redirect', function(res) {
  console.log('Redirected');
})
.end(function(err, res){
  console.log(res);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know by heart but it looks like postman follows the 301 (Moved Permanently) and your super agent is not. 301 is a redirect response. See [details](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)

Normally you should handle the 301 responses in your code. At the response you will find the redirected URL.

Answer (score 1):

in postman, if it got HTTP 301 response it will redirect automatically if you don't see 301 response and you get an actual response after redirect but in superagent, it won't automatically redirect and you see 301 in response.

you can enable interceptor to disable automaticlly redirect in postman.

most of website use this header to say to browser that it should redirct for example in some website if you call http://target.com it get 301 response and redirect to https://target.com

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for you answers, I may found my problem : it's in fact the server's wait for application/x-www-form-urlencoded format.
[image]

How can i translate this in superagent HTTP request ?
I tried :

```
postData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request
            .post(this.url)
            .send('destinations={"1": "testa"}')
            .send('stopId=2643')
            .send('lineId=1150')
            .send('sens=2')
            .end((err, res) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(res)
        })
    })
}
```

Ok, I found the solution, for other people, I post this above :

```
request
        .post(this.url)
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        .send({destinations: '{"1":"test"}'})
        .send({stopId: "2643"})
        .send({lineId: "1150"})
        .send({sens: "2"})
        .end(function(err, res){
         console.log(res);
      })
```